# Does it work to use 'dotnet ef database update ' to connect to remote server（Windows Server 2012 + SQL Server 2014）

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core

I use the command `dotnet ef database update` to connect to the remote server （SQL Server 2014). No firewall and SQL Server is configured correctly. But some exceptions occurred as follows:

> Using the integrated security when the connection is established, SSPI handshake failure, the error code 0 x8009030c, state 14; The connection has been closed. Reason: AcceptSecurityContext failure. The Windows error code indicating the cause of the failure. Login failed

This is my connection string:

```
Server = 114.55.xx.xx;Database=IdentityDatabase;User ID=sa;Password=xxxxxxx;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

Comment: By remote do you mean on the internet somewhere? It's unlikely that windows integrated security will work as you need to share an active directory. You'll need to use SQL Security instead. Firstly remove the `Integrated Security=SSPI;` portion from your connection string. Secondly read and understand the difference between SQL Logins and windows authenticated logins.